# How to decode symbols &quot; and others symbols to manipulate this data in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In PHP, I put the `$data_attributes` array into the `data-additional-color-data attribute` of one HTML element:

```
$data_attributes = [
      312 => [
        'name' => 'Black',
        'hex' => '#000000',
        'src' => 'http://sitename/files/pms_colors/Black.png'
      ],
      313 => [
        'name' => 'Metallic',
        'hex' => '#D3D4DE',
        'src' => 'http://sitename/files/pms_colors/Metallic.png'
      ]
    ];
$entity_form['field_pms_colors']['#attributes']['data-additional-color-data'] = Json::encode($data_attributes);
```

And I see in the browser’s devtools that in the markup the element looks like this:

```
<div class="field--name-field-pms-colors" data-additional-color-data="{&quot;312&quot;:{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Black&quot;,&quot;hex&quot;:&quot;#000000&quot;,&quot;src&quot;:&quot;http:\/\/sitename\/sites\/default\/files\/pms_colors\/Black.png&quot;},&quot;313&quot;:{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Metallic Silver&quot;,&quot;hex&quot;:&quot;#D3D4DE&quot;,&quot;src&quot;:&quot;http:\/\/sitename\/sites\/default\/files\/pms_colors\/Metallic%20Silver.png&quot;}}"></div>
```

This is one element and its properties must be with it:

```
      312 => [
        'name' => 'Black',
        'hex' => '#000000',
        'src' => 'http://sitename/files/pms_colors/Black.png'
      ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific decoding to be done, as JavaScript will decode this when accessing the data attribute like this:

```
// Get the HTML element of interest:
let element = document.querySelector("div.field--name-field-pms-colors");
// Read the data- attribute of interest:
let content = element.dataset.additionalColorData;
// Output it: no decoding of HTML entities needed -- there is no literal &quot;
console.log(content);
// Parse the JSON into an object
let obj = JSON.parse(content);
// Use the object...
```